# Find the minimal amount of letter swaps needed for sorting a string

Tags: python, sorting

I have a problem where I need to find the minimal amount of letter swaps needed to sort a string. With each move, I can swap the position of two characters (not necessarily adjacent) and I would need to find the minimum amount of swaps.

I've solved a similar problem before in binary (required the bit swaps to be adjacent). So sorting `101010 => 000111` would return `6`, but cannot find a way to generalise my solution:

```
def sort(s):
    ones = 0
    res = 0
    for b in s:
        if b == "1":
            ones += 1
        if b == "0":
            res += ones
    return res
```

Should I incorporate the `ord()` function here somehow to change the problem to deal with integers instead? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused about the problem definition. For the code you posted `sort('101010') == 6` not `000111`. You're not really sorting or swapping anything.

Comment: Res is the minimum amount of swaps.

Comment: @Tomerikoo the code above is restricted to only swap adjacent bits. Edited the question.

Comment: This might be handy: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-swaps-required-sort-array/

Answer (score 1):

The minimum number of swaps is determined by the [cycle decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation) of the [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) that the letters are in, relative to the sorted order. For example, suppose the word is `"wonderful"`, then the sorted order is `"deflnoruw"` and the cycles are

- `w → d`, `d → l`, `l → w`
- `o → e`, `e → n`, `n → f`, `f → r`, `r → o`
- `u → u`

The lengths of the cycles are 3, 5 and 1 respectively, so we subtract 1 from each length to get the minimum number of swaps required to perform those cycles: 2 + 4 + 0 = 6 swaps. Equivalently, the number of swaps is the string length minus the number of cycles: 9 - 3 = 6.

So, your algorithm will need to work according to this idea; it may help to investigate the [cycle sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort) which finds the cycles to actually do the sorting. Note also that it's a bit more complicated than the above example when the word has repeated letters.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below program. This checks minimum number of swaps by trying from `0` to `n-1` unique swaps, for a string of length `n`.
I have tested it with few strings.

```py
input =list("CABCAB")
output=list("AABBCC")

def get_map(output,input):
    #Create map of output to input, removing existing match
    map={}
    for i,j in zip(output,input):
        if i!=j:
            if i in map:
                map[i].append(j)
            else:
                map[i]=[j]
    return map

def get_chain(map,char,find,swap):
    #Create chain of elements
    if swap<=1:
        for j in map[char]:
            if find in map[j]:
                return [char,j]
        return []
    for c in map[char]:
        chain=get_chain(map,c,find,swap-1)
        if chain:
            return [char]+chain
        else:
            return chain

map=get_map(output,input)
total_swaps=0;
for swap in range(1,len(output)):
    c=0
    while c<len(map.keys()):
        chars=list(map.keys())
        chain=get_chain(map,chars[c],chars[c],swap)
        if chain:
            chain.extend(chars[c])
            for e in range(len(chain)-1):                
                map[chain[e]].remove(chain[e+1])
                if not map[chain[e]]:
                    del map[chain[e]]
            total_swaps+=len(chain)-2
            c=0
        else:
            c+=1
    if not map:
        break

print(f"Number of swaps: {total_swaps}")
```

**Output**

```
Number of swaps: 2
```